# Get current pagetitle in Typo3 in Hmenu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to get the pagetitle of the current page I'm on in Typo3. I want to wrap a div - Box for a Hmenu. That works, but I also want the Title in the div to be the title of the current page. My typoscript looks like this

```
temp.pagetitle = TEXT
temp.pagetitle.field=title 
page=PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10.marks.LEFT_MENU = HMENU
page.10.marks.LEFT_MENU {
special = directory
special.value = {$pwcms.linkesMenu.rootSeitenID}
excludeUidList = {$pwcms.linkesMenu.nichtSichtbareSeiten}
stdWrap.preCObject < temp.pagetitle
stdWrap.wrap = <div class="bigBox shadow"> <div class="csc-header csc-header-n1">
<h1 class="csc-firstHeader">temp.pagetitle</h1></div>| </div>
stdWrap.wrap.insertData = 1
```

If I save these settings and reload the page, the caption in my div Box just says "temp.pagetitle"

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be some kind of this way:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10.marks.LEFT_MENU = HMENU
page.10.marks.LEFT_MENU {
  special = directory
  special.value = {$pwcms.linkesMenu.rootSeitenID}
  excludeUidList = {$pwcms.linkesMenu.nichtSichtbareSeiten}
  stdWrap.preCObject = TEXT
  stdWrap.preCObject.data = page : file
  stdWrap.preCObject.wrap = <div class="bigBox shadow"> <div class="csc-header csc-header-n1">
  <h1 class="csc-firstHeader"> | </h1> </div> </div>
}
```